# New MySQL version breaking queries

Tags: mysql, version

I moved a MySQL database from a server using **MySQL 5.1.36** to a server using **MySQL 5.7.11** and most of the `INSERT` statements now don't work. A previous developer created this app, and I'm trying to fix this query.

Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO arts.tblmainrequest 
select UUID(),'Aetna','Test','Test','555555','20160921','\\Base Folder\',
  NULL,'testdoc.doc',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
  NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
  NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
  '20160920','test record','Y','400889', now()
```

Here is the create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblmainrequest` (
  `reqUUID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `patientlname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `patientfname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MRN` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DischargeDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BaseFolder` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecordsMailed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `OriginalReqFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHHURCommitteeLetter` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHHURCommitteeLetterFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MedRecsDeliveryMethod` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrackingNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrelimFindings` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrelimFindingsFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHHPrelimResponseUM` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHHPrelimResponseUMFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHHPrelimResponseMR` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHHPrelimResponseMRFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinalReviewFindings` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinalReviewFindingsFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinalResponseSHH` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinalResponseSHHFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingRequestSHH` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingRequestSHHFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingCorrespondenceUnnamed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingCorrespondenceUnnamedFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingDateScheduled` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingDateScheduledFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingDecision` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HearingDecisionFileName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailedBusOffice` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` longtext,
  `Active` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reqUUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Am am pretty certain that you get a precise error message. _Read it_.

Comment: Yes: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.doc' - right where the 1st red squiggle is - again, I'm researching to see why this is not working on this version of MySQL.

Comment: create that insert stmt as txt not a picture. Pictures are useless. do a `show create table tblmainrequest` and publish that.

Comment: OK, altered original post with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the second \ for the folder, \Base Folder****

Otherwise, mysql takes **** to as escape char and the following ' becomes the value of the field, and cause the following syntax are wrong.

Comment: Many thanks! Not sure how this was working in previous MySQL, but that fixed it.